# JWT Security Best Practice with Certificate

Tags: security, jwt

Any security experts here? We have built out a JWT authentication flow with a client, but they keep asking for more and more information. So far we have provided:

- Client ID
- Client Secret
- server.key (private key)/(iss)
- public key
- endpoint (aud)
- username (sub)

It's been a bit of a slog, and to be honest I am not super familiar with the process. But they are trying now to store the private key in their keystore, and are asking for the server.crt to be able to store it. They are trying to store it in PKCS#8 format.

Now, as I understand it, they should not need that, and it can actually be a security issue because they can create their own tokens using this, correct? My gut says they don't need this, and I pushed back on it, but they are saying they need it to move forward. Can anyone answer if that is the truth? Or should I push back and tell them no?

Looking [at this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538047/jwt-private-public-key-confusion), it seems that having the server.crt would give them the ability to validate themselves..?

Whatever tool they are using says that they need the `servcer.crt` to even put it in their keystore. I don't know what they are using, so I can't validate that.

Comment: An important clarification that needs to be made here: Are you using the JWT flow to authorize with your client (doesn't matter if it's SFDC or something else), or is your client using the JWT flow to authorize in your SFDC org?

Comment: We are using the JWT flow to give an external user access. We are trying to follow the flow [in this SF article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5). So our understanding is that they can use the private key to sign a JWT and connect to SF, and SF will return an auth token for them to log in with and perform their HTTP Post.

Comment: They sign with their private key that they should never expose to you.  If your client's application is user-facing, using JWT flow to give external user access is very difficult to do in a secure fashion. If the users' credentials are in SF , new and recommended approach is to use [Headless Login](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_headless_auth.htm&release=242&type=5). Credentials not in SF = look at SSO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Some background information

- Every API call made to Salesforce needs a Salesforce User (which gets used to run the actual call)

  - Put another way, OAuth allows you to execute an action *on behalf of some other (Salesforce) User*
  - I *believe* that this needs to be a user with a full Salesforce license (i.e. not a "Chatter Free User" or something like that), though I'm not 100% certain on that
- The JWT flow is generally for when you can't ask the user to input their own username/password (the "headless" or non-interactive scenario, e.g. When an Apex class in one org needs to make a callout to another SFDC org). If it's possible for your client to enter credentials, the "interactive" scenario, you should probably use a different flow
- You *can* get away with not creating a dedicated user and allocating a license, but that has some serious security implications (whoever is obtaining the access token can do everything that the Salesforce User that token was granted for can do)

### OAuth in general

OAuth deals with *authorization*. It doesn't tell you who someone is, it tells you *what they are allowed to do*. By using OAuth, you're giving your client the ability to do everything that the user you're allowing them to use is able to do.

### On the JWT flow

Assuming this is the correct flow to use, your client only requires the following information:

- The Client Id (a.k.a. the Client Key) for your connected app (the `iss` parameter in the JWT)
- The url you would normally use to log into your org (generally either "https://login.salesforce.com" for production orgs, or "https://test.salesforce.com" for sandboxes) (the `aud` parameter in the JWT)
- The username of the person to act on behalf of (e.g. `chance@myCompany.com`) (the `sub` parameter in the JWT)
- An expiration time, in seconds since the unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) (the `exp` parameter in the JWT)

  - This is when the JWT itself expires, not when the access token you get as a result of exchanging the JWT expires. An access token is like a session, and its timeout is controlled in Salesforce through the connected app, user, or org security settings (in that order)

Your client **does not need the client secret** in this flow. It might be a good idea to create an entirely new connected app (to get a different client id and secret).

They also need to sign the JWT with the *private* key of a public-private keypair. **Your client should be the one to generate and control that keypair**, and they should give you the public key (as a `.crt` file) which you'll use to configure your connected app.

### Salesforce is the <strike>keymaster</strike> party that controls generating access tokens

Your client having the private key means that you shouldn't use that keypair for anything else. Since you both have the private key, neither of you should actually use that keypair. The public key in asymmetric encryption is *meant* to be shared with others.

Having both the public and private keys doesn't give your client any superpowers. They still have to make a request to Salesforce to get an access token (using the private key). An access token is only valid for a single user in a single org for a limited period of time.

### It's the connected app and the user that's more the focus of security here

The public-private keypair is instrumental in being able to use the JWT flow, but that doesn't mean much if you don't have a connected app.

The security boundary here is the connected app that you've created. When you have the details of that connected app, you can start making requests to Salesforce. Those requests won't succeed unless you also have user credentials in the org though<sup>1</sup>.

All of that is to say that you don't really control what access your client has through the connected app itself (other than a super-coarse, binary has some access/has no access). You control access through the user you allow them to use.

While it is cheaper to use an existing user in your org, if security is an honest concern of yours then you should create a dedicated user in your org for this (where you can use profiles, roles, custom permissions, and permission sets to define what they can and cannot do).

<sup>1: While the JWT flow doesn't need the user's password, you can't use the JWT flow without first using a different OAuth flow. That OAuth flow needs to generate a refresh token, and those flows are interactive and require a password.</sup>

Comment: This is extremely thorough and adds context and details to what I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add a comment to expand on Derek's excellent writeup, addressing the specific use case of the Security Certificate with the OAuth JWT Bearer Token flow.

If you were to instead use the OAuth Client Credentials flow, one of the simpler methods for a server-to-server integration (where you don't need to tie API callouts back to individual users), you'd have direct access to the credentials needed to connect to the API and your connected app (because said credentials are generated *by you* during the connected app setup).

In contrast, the JWT flow requires setting up a certificate/private key pair. You may notice that if you create a self-signed certificate inside SF, you are given no way to access the paired private key! This is because it is kept hidden by SF, and the certificate you create that way is meant for other use cases, not the one in this thread.

However, similarly, the concept with the JWT flow you're executing is that *you, the recipient of callouts, do not need to know the Private Key for the certificate used in your private app*. In fact, it compromises security for you to know it, because anyone with that key will be able to request access tokens to your org through the connected app (granted, they'll need a few other data points too, like an accepted username.)

**Therefore, the intended process is this:**

1. You set up the Connected App in SF, along with the associated SF user, and that user's scope of access.
2. The connecting party should generate a security certificate and private key pair. **They keep the Private Key for themselves and share with no one**, including you. What they send you is the certificate itself, divorced from the private key, which you can upload to your Connected App.
3. Now when the connecting party uses the Private Key to sign their Auth token request, it will be identified as valid due to the matching Certificate on the connected app, without you or anyone else being able to steal the Private Key and spoof callouts as if you were the actual connecting party.